# Laravel Fortify password reset link giving ArgumentCountError when clicked

Tags: laravel, laravel-fortify

Using Laravel 9 and Fortify, I can get a link sent by email that should enable the user to reset their password, as per [the docs](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/fortify#resetting-the-password).

This link has the form /api/reset-password?token=yadayada&email=abc@example.com

However the backend responds with an error:

```
local.ERROR: Too few arguments to function Illuminate\Routing\RouteFileRegistrar::{closure}(), 0 passed in /home/dan/www/digisam/digisam-prm/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php
```

The closure passed to Fortify:resetPasswordView() at boot is never called.

The route **is** registered:

```
php artisan route:list
...
  POST      api/reset-password ..........//............. password.update # Laravel\Fortify # NewPasswordController@store
  GET|HEAD  api/reset-password ..........//............. password.reset
```

but in the list, no controller or method is listed for the GET api as opposed to the POST. Not sure why, this is a fairly vanilla Fortify installation.

Any ideas for where to look next?

Comment: It should be a post request to `/reset-password` API. You're making a get request is what I understand from your question.

Comment: Post parameters aren't passed like this `?token=yadayada&email=abc@example.com`

Comment: When user clicks the link, its a GET. But no worries, I just worked it out. Turned out someone had put the /reset-password route handler in api.php, and it was buggy. I thought this would be a built-in Fortify route, didn't even think to look there!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turned out to be code in route/api.php that was not functional.